# Why doesn't the objective-c runtime implement the opposite of method class_addProtocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

One would assume that if the obj-c runtime implements the method `class_addProtocol`, it would also implement the counterpart of this, something like `class_removeProtocol`. However, it seems to me that there is no such method. I'm curious why...

See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449172/why-doesnt-the-objective-c-runtime-implement-the-opposite-of-method-class-addpr?noredirect=1#comment35944444_23449172) for a scenario when having `class_removeProtocol` would come in handy.

Comment: Why would removeProtocol be necessary in the runtime?  I can't think of any reason.

Comment: @stevesliva easy: think of when addProtocol is necessary and think of the opposite :)

Comment: What would removing conformance to anything in a dynamic language change?  Just because you happen to not declare conformance to NSCopying, doesn't mean the methods aren't still there.

Comment: @kadam -- does the runtime support renaming a class once it is named?  Modifying inheritance?  I get that some things like a class's methods aren't static by design, but it seems like the protocols implemented are supposed to be.

Comment: @CodaFi one example would be conforming to UIKeyInput. On iOS the OS brings the soft keyboard on screen, when the firstResponder conforms to UIKeyInput. I'm dealing with an unusual situation when a firstResponder would need the soft keyboard on screen in some circumstances, while not in others. One way of achieving this would be to toggle (using add/removeProtocol) the conformance of the firstResponder to the UIKeyInput protocol.

Comment: @stevesliva Yes, in the absence of the method `class_removeProtocol`, my other approach that seems to achieve the desired effect is to use `object_setClass` to toggle between two classes; one that implements the protocol and one that does not.

Comment: Huh.  Interesting-- might be worth inserting in the question the background of what you're looking to do.  I didn't vote you down, but I think the generic "why is the API like this" aspect got a downvote.

Comment: In thinking on your needs-- can't you override the `conformsToProtocol` *instance* method for your object's class, so that you can toggle it for the instance you want?

Comment: If it works, you should answer.  I'm curious whether `conformsToProtocol` is checked every time it needs to be.  Might be interesting to log calls to your implementation of it.